# moving from sql server to cassandra

Tags: sql, mongodb, cassandra

I have a data intensive project for which I wrote the code recently, the data and sp live in a MS SQL db.  My initial estimate is that the db will grow to 50TB, then it will become fairly static in growth.  The final application will perform lots of row level look ups and readings, with a very small percentile of db write backs.

With the above scenario in mind, its being suggested that I should look at a NoSQL option in order to scale to the large load of data and transactions, and after a bit of research the roads leads to Cassandra (while considering MongoDB as a second alternative)

I would appreciate your guidance with the following set of initial questions:

-Does Cassandra support the concept of store procs?

-Would I be able to install and run the 50TB db on a single node (single Windows Server)?

-Does Cassandra support/leverage multiple CPUs in single server (ex: 4 CPUs)?

-Would open source version be able to support the 50TB db? or would I need to purchase the ENT version?

Regards,
-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does Cassandra support the concept of store procs?

Cassandra does not support stored procedures.  However there is a feature called "prepared statements" which allows you to submit a CQL query once, and then have it executed multiple times with different parameters.  But the set of things you can do with prepared statements is limited to regular CQL.  In particular you can not do things like loops, conditional statements or other interesting things.  But you do get some measure of protection against injection attacks and savings on multiple compilations.

> Would I be able to install and run the 50TB db on a single node (single Windows Server)?

I am not aware of anything that would prevent you from running a 50TB database on one node, but you may require lots of memory to keep things relatively smooth, as you RAM/storage ratio is likely to be very low and thus impact your ability to cache disk data meaningfully.  What is not recommended, however, is running a production setup on Windows.  Cassandra uses some Linux specific IO optimizations, and is tested much more thoroughly on Linux.  Far-out setups like you're suggesting are especially likely to be untested on Windows.

> Does Cassandra support/leverage multiple CPUs in single server (ex: 4 CPUs)?

Yes

> Would open source version be able to support the 50TB db? or would I need to purchase the ENT version?

The Apache distro does not have any usage limits baked into it (it makes little sense in an open source project, if you think about it).  Neither does the free version from DataStax, the Community Edition.

Comment: A DBA from another forum provided me with the following comments, are these comments valid for Cassandra (et al)?  "Break it down this way, most of the NoSQL solutions are awesome at collecting data, not so good at reporting from it. So, if your main focus is collection, NoSQL is probably a viable alternative, especially during the gather data til we get to 50tb phase of the operation. But after that, as soon you want to run a query that cuts across the data in any fashion other than the id/value pair of HADOOP or one of the other NoSQL solutions, you'll be extremely stuck."

Comment: This seems correct.  What is true is that you cannot run arbitrary queries.  Selecting one row by primary key is always fast; you can also get one specific non-primary key query (sometimes a couple) per table to run very fast by designing table schema to make that particular search run fast (you can also store the same data in multiple tables to support multiple queries).  And then if you ever want to perform joins or do more intricate slices, you have to use Hadoop, which is slow as molasses.